# How do I query DataStore for a subid with out getting an error of Possible unhandled Promise rejection object is not a function

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I tried querying DataStore for a user's subId, which I know is there, however anytime I try this I get an error message saying: Possible unhandled Promise rejection (id:0) TypeError: Object is not a function.

I am sorry I was unable to type out the code because Stackoverflow kept telling my post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted, and that I should indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button and I don't know how to do that. So I just uploaded a photo.[Photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itROP.png)

```js
import { createContext, useState,useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {Auth, DataStore} from 'aws-amplify';
import { User } from "../models";

const AuthContext = createContext({})

const AuthContextProvider = ({children})=>{
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null)
    const [dbUser, setDbUser] = useState(null) 
    const sub = authUser?.attributes?.sub;

    useEffect(()=>{
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache: true}).then(setAuthUser)
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        DataStore.query(User, (user)=>user.sub("eq", sub)).then((users)=>setDbUser(users[0]))
    }, [sub])


    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{authUser, dbUser, sub, setDbUser }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContextProvider;

export const useAuthContext = ()=> useContext(AuthContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there is something new called 'Lazy loading & nested query predicates for AWS Amplify DataStore'. It is the change of the syntax from:
Before: DataStore.query(Post, p => p.id(‘eq’, ‘123’))
Now: DataStore.query(Post, p => p.id.eq(‘123’))

So, in my case, it is:

```js
    useEffect(()=>{
        DataStore.query(User, (user)=>user.sub.eq(sub)).then((users)=>setDbUser(users[0]))
    }, [sub])
```